# Remove specific parts of a link

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to remove a specific part of a url.
Would this be done with split?

Example:

> test.com/title/name_title1/01
>
> test.com/title/name_title_2/02
>
> test.com/title/name_title-10/10
>
> test.com/title/name_title_120/120

I want to remove part 01 leaving like this:

> test.com/title/name_title1/
>
> test.com/title/name_title_2/
>
> test.com/title/name_title-10/
>
> test.com/title/name_title_120/

Comment: how about `String::lastIndexOf` - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-string-lastindexof-method/

What you basically want to do, is check what is the last index of your "/" character. Because according to you, you want everything after that last slash removed.

```
String link = "whatever your link is"; 
int lastIndex = link.lastIndexOf("/"); 
String newString = link.substring(0, lastIndex+1);
```

And your new string should be the string up to the index of your last slash.

Hope this helps!

EnhancedLoop7

Comment: pleasure is all mine :)